# INDEX formula for criteria with multiple outputs

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

This is the formula I am using, however, it is outputting the incorrect account. It seemed to be working when I tested it on a single sheet but when I changed the output and input sheet it stopped out putting the correct accounts.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$C$1000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$1000=Adkins!$E$1,ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$1000)),ROW(Sheet1!1:1)),2)),"",INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$C$1000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$1000=Adkins!$E$1,ROW($B$1:$B$1000)),ROW(Sheet1!1:1)),2))
```

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcyvm.png)

[image]

[Sheet:Adkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVk4D.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=iferror(index(sheet1!b:b, aggregate(15, 6, row($2:$99)/(sheet1!a$2:a$99=adkins!e$1), row(1:1))), text(,))
```

The iferror reduces the calculation and code significantly.

Comment: That is a lot cleaner! However, it is not outputting anything.

Comment: My apologies; it should have been `(sheet1!a$2:a$99=adkins!e$1`

Comment: So I am working through the names and I have reached the name that is in the 100th row and the formula will not output after that. I changed the sheet1!a$2:a$99=adkins!e$1 to sheet1!a$2:a$1000=adkins!e$1 but it did not change anything. How do I get it to use all rows up to 1000?

Comment: Nvm. I changed aggregate(15, 6, row($2:$99) to aggregate(15, 6, row($2:$1000) also and it worked.

Comment: try `row($2:$1000)/(sheet1!a$2:a$1000=adkins!e$1)` (change 99 to 1000 in **two** places)